# Apache Django Error - Loading Module From lib64 But Expected To Load From Different Directory

Tags: python-3.x, django, linux, apache, centos7

I have configured apache, python virtual environment, and Django. I'm trying to host the Django in apache. I verified the Django working fine by running the command "./manage.py runserver 192.168.0.107". But this is not working in Apache, in apache, if I load the page I'm getting 500 Internal Server errors.

In the Apache HTTP log, I got the below error message.

```
[Mon Nov 08 18:21:51.248632 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 1812] [remote 192.168.0.105:50224] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.9.0 or later is required (found 3.7.17)
```

In Python, I verified the SQLite version and it says 3.36.0 and not 3.7.17, refer to the details below.

```
Python 3.7.12 (default, Nov  8 2021, 09:02:58)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database>>>
>>>
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
>>> Database.sqlite_version_info
(3, 36, 0)
```

I tried to find the version that apache actually using, I used the grep command and I found it was using SQLite 3.7.17 from lib64

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep -rnw /usr -e '3.7.17'

/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc:10:Version: 3.7.17

/usr/include/sqlite3.h:110:#define SQLITE_VERSION        "3.7.17"
```

**REQUIREMENT**
I need to clean or uninstall package 3.7.17 and tell Apache or WSGI to use 3.36.0

Below is the configuration of my apache, I have this configuration in file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf"

```
Alias /static /home/rafiq/myproject/static
<Directory /home/rafiq/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /home/rafiq/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/rafiq/myprojectenv:/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rafiq/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

WSGI Configuration Details in Python Django.

```
[root@localhost ~]# vi /home/rafiq/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/rafiq/myproject')
sys.path.append('/home/rafiq/myproject/myproject')
sys.path.append('/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages')


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Below are the sys.path details from apache logs.

```
['/home/rafiq/myprojectenv', '/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/rafiq/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myproject/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/rafiq/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myproject/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/rafiq/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myproject/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/rafiq/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myproject/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/rafiq/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myproject/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/rafiq/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myproject/myproject', '/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Below is sys.path details directly from python3.7

```
[rafiq@localhost ~]$ source myprojectenv/bin/activate
(myprojectenv) [rafiq@localhost ~]$ python3.7
Python 3.7.12 (default, Nov  8 2021, 09:02:58)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/rafiq/myprojectenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

**Could someone please help to fix this issue, not sure how to tell apache to use SQLite 3.36.0**

**Thank You**

Comment: According to the docs you should use `python-home` instead of `python-path` in `WSGIDaemonProcess` for a virtual environment - `WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/rafiq/myprojectenv` https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html#python-path

Comment: @IainShelvington, in python-home one can specify sys.prefix, in python-path one can specify list of paths that can be accessed, and one can supply multiple directories that are separated by comma. Note: I tried with python-home, that didn't resolved the problem. I have sqlite 3.7.17 in /usr/lib64 and I have sqlite 3.36.0 in /usr/local/lib, I need to use sqlite 3.36 and need to uninstall 3.7.